# ( laravel - Php ) i want a code that shows total users in database

Tags: php, laravel

in user panel i want to show total registerd users in my site ,

Example : 
Total Users On Our Network : 55
The  55 i want it to get how many users on our site from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$usersCount = DB::table('users')->count();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Comment: how to show it in site ? like echo ?

Comment: $usersCount = DB::table('users')->count(); dd($usersCount); try this